# Overflow with animation won't work

Tags: html, css, animation, overflow

I'm trying to prevent overflow on my website, even though i have divs that flows outside with animation.
You can see it at [this link](http://tweezers.co).

I did `overflow-x:hidden
overflow-y:hidden`

on the body, html, headers, footer and the cloud divs.
**It works just fine on desktop browsers**, but on mobile you can scroll both vertical and horizontal.

Why is that? there is nothing odd in my code. the animations start at -200px and end on 2000px (left).

This is my HTML:

```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, height=device-height, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
            <meta name = "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content = "yes" /> 
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Tweezers</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h2 class="tk-expo-sans-pro">we're working on our awesome website</h2>
        <img id="logo" src="img/logo.gif"/>
        <div class="land"></div>
        <div class="cloud1"></div>
        <div class="cloud2"></div>
        <div class="cloud3"></div>
        <footer>
            <h3 class="tk-expo-sans-pro">meanwhile you can reach us via:</h3>
            <a href="http://facebook.com/tweezers.co"><div class="icon-uniE600"></div></a>
            <div class="icon-uniE601"></div>
            <div class="icon-uniE602"></div>
            <div class="icon-uniE603"></div>
        </footer>
        <!---JS FILES-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/cxg8ost.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
    </body>

</html>
```

What I'm missing?
Thanks, Boaz.

Answer (score 1):

In which mobile device are you checking your page and in which browser?

There is a similar issue in firefox 18 Android device. Please refer this : http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/css3-transformations-showing-content-outside-overflowhidden-region-in-firefoxandroid/

Comment: I tried on Safari (iPhone 4&5) and Chrome (Nexus). will check it! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following meta tag in your HTML page,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height">
```

Comment: I have it (edited the question, added the html code).. and it still have this weird overflow on mobile. strange :(

Comment: sure, I have overflow:hidden on all of my containers. I even did overflow-x and overflow-y hidden.